# Joomla 2.5 override to not allow author to edit his published article

Tags: joomla2.5

With Joomla 2.5 an author is allowed to edit his/her article even after it is published.

I would like to perhaps use a Joomla override to not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

See the `Edit Own` option in `Article Manager Options` which states the following:

> Allows users in the group to edit any content they submitted in this extension.

Go to `Article Manager -> Article Manager Options -> Permissions tab -> Click 'Author'`

An image showing where it's located: [image]